# High memory leakage is observed in EDGE IE11 mode as compared to IE with Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Recently, we have upgraded our Selenium version from 2.53 to 4.1.2 to enable testing of our application on MS EDGE IE11 mode. The reason behind running our application on EDGE IE11 mode is because IE is going to be deprecated soon. Hence, we decided to move to EDGE in IE11 mode. We had observed previously that memory leak was fine with IE. But when we migrated our scripts to EDGE IE 11 mode, we are seeing high memory leakage with EDGE IE11 as compared to IE11.

Selenium Version: 4.1.2,
Execution Mode : IE mode and EDGE IE11 mode,
IE Driver version : 4.0.0.0

Did anyone else facing similar kind of issues with EDGE IE11 mode?

Comment: Does the issue also happen in Edge IE mode without Selenium? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? Besides, you can refer to this answer and try the solution to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The official [Selenium Github Repository](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) is a great resource for you to reference, already found some resolved issues that may suit your problem: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10615
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10609
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10495

Comment: None of these links address memory leak differences between IE 11 stand alone and EDGE IE 11 Enterprise mode.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same.  Workflows in IE11 stand alone do not leak.  Running those same work flows in EDGE browser IE 11 Enterprise Mode leaks terribly.  I haven't been able to find many other reports of this or MS addressing this.